# Android ICS widgets (switch) and older versions

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to have a switch widget for ICS versions, but a checkbox for pre ICS? If so, how?

I'm not worried about other components, only switch.

***MY SOLUTION***

Seeing as switch and checkbox both inherit from CompoundButton, I just did this

```
((CompoundButton)findViewById(R.id.swTax)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            calculateValues();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a separate layout XML file for ICS versions by placing it in a separate layout folder, e.g. `layout-v14`. To prevent a lot of duplicate XML, use one main layout file and include the widget. The resulting file structure would look something like this:

- layout

  - mylayout.xml
  - widget.xml
- layout-v14

  - widget.xml

In `mylayout.xml` you would have something like:

```
<include layout="@layout/widget" />
```

In the `Activity` for this layout you will have to check the version as well before setting up any interaction with either the `CheckBox` or `Switch` widget:

```
int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (version >= 14) {
    // get your Switch view and set up listeners etc
}
else {
    // get your CheckBox view and set up listeners etc
}
```

Comment: btw, android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is available in API 4 and higher

Comment: You'd probably want `layout-v14` and `case 14: case 15:` because the first version of ICS was actually 14.

Comment: Another idea is to use the layout xml and in the code use the super type of CompoundButton, then you don't need to do the version logic but have access to most of the methods such as setChecked and setOnCheckedChangeListener. CompoundButton switch = (CompoundButton)findViewById(R.id.switch);

Comment: there's a nice lecture about it on google IO : https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/106/ slide 32

Comment: Is there any way to use the ICS switch in lesser SDK versions?. I have seen a application who have used ICS switch and it works with lesser SDK versions. Ref: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azumio.android.sleeptime

Answer (score 1):

I've tried every solution that i found but non of them were fit my needs, so i created my own widget wich is used ObjectAnimator from nineOld compatibility lib and works pretty fine on any android API.

```
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.myapp.utilities.AppUtils;
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator;
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator;

public class SwitchButton extends RelativeLayout {

public static final int TEXT_SIZE = 11;

public float HANDLE_SHIFT = -40f;
public float TEXT_RIGHT_SHIFT = 40f;
public static int BUTTON_ID = 0x00009999;
public static int TEXT_ID = 0x00008888;


private Button handleButton;
private RoboTextView textView;
private boolean switchEnabled;
private String yesStr;
private String noStr;
private int TEXT_LEFT_PADDING = 13;

private ObjectAnimator animateHandleLeftShift;
private ObjectAnimator animateHandleRightShift;
private int HANDLE_BUTTON_HEIGHT = 22;
private int HANDLE_BUTTON_WIDTH = 42;
private ObjectAnimator animateTextLeftShift;
private ObjectAnimator animateTextRightShift;


public SwitchButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    onCreate(context);
}


private void onCreate(Context context) {

    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    TEXT_LEFT_PADDING *= density;

    HANDLE_BUTTON_HEIGHT *= density;
    HANDLE_BUTTON_WIDTH *= density;

    HANDLE_SHIFT *= density;
    TEXT_RIGHT_SHIFT *= density;

    yesStr = getContext().getString(R.string.yes).toUpperCase();
    noStr = getContext().getString(R.string.no).toUpperCase();

    {// Button
        handleButton = new Button(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LayoutParams(HANDLE_BUTTON_WIDTH, HANDLE_BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        handleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_switch_handle_selector);
        handleButton.setId(BUTTON_ID);

        addView(handleButton, buttonParams);
    }


    {// Text
        textView = new RoboTextView(getContext());
        LayoutParams textParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        textView.setText(yesStr);
        textView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.new_normal_gray));
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, TEXT_SIZE);
        textView.setPadding(TEXT_LEFT_PADDING, 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setFont(RoboTextView.ROBOTO_BOLD_FONT);
        textView.setId(TEXT_ID);
        float shadowRadius = 0.5f ;
        float shadowDx = 0;
        float shadowDy = 1;
        textView.setShadowLayer(shadowRadius, shadowDx, shadowDy, Color.BLACK);

        addView(textView, textParams);
    }
    initFlipAnimation();

}

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    handleButton.setOnClickListener(l);
    textView.setOnClickListener(l);
}

public void toggle(View view){
    if (AppUtils.HONEYCOMB_PLUS_API && view.getId() == TEXT_ID) { // ignore text clicks
        return;
    }

    switchEnabled = !switchEnabled;

    if (switchEnabled) {
        // animate handle to the left
        animateHandleLeftShift.start();
        animateTextLeftShift.start();

        textView.setText(noStr);
    } else {
        animateHandleRightShift.start();
        animateTextRightShift.start();

        textView.setText(yesStr);
    }
}

private android.view.animation.Interpolator accelerator = new LinearInterpolator();
private static final int DURATION = 70;

private void initFlipAnimation() {


    animateHandleLeftShift = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(handleButton, "translationX", 0f, HANDLE_SHIFT);
    animateHandleLeftShift.setDuration(DURATION);
    animateHandleLeftShift.setInterpolator(accelerator);

    animateHandleRightShift = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(handleButton, "translationX", HANDLE_SHIFT, 0f);
    animateHandleRightShift.setDuration(DURATION);
    animateHandleRightShift.setInterpolator(accelerator);

    animateHandleLeftShift.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator anim) {
            // TODO
        }
    });


    animateTextLeftShift = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "translationX", 0f, TEXT_RIGHT_SHIFT);
    animateTextLeftShift.setDuration(DURATION);
    animateTextLeftShift.setInterpolator(accelerator);

    animateTextRightShift = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "translationX", TEXT_RIGHT_SHIFT, 0f);
    animateTextRightShift.setDuration(DURATION);
    animateTextRightShift.setInterpolator(accelerator);
}
```

}

In XML

```
<com.chess.SwitchButton
    android:id="@+id/ratedGameSwitch"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_switch_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_switch_height"
    android:background="@drawable/button_switch_back"
    />
```

In the Activity/Fragment you only have to findViewById and set clickListener to it, and in onClick callback handle it:

```
switchButton = (SwitchButton) optionsView.findViewById(R.id.ratedGameSwitch);
switchButton.setOnClickListener(this);


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == SwitchButton.BUTTON_ID  || view.getId() == SwitchButton.TEXT_ID){
        switchButton.toggle(view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a iOS like Segmented control (extension of radio button) with on/off instead of a switch then you can use the same code for old and new SDK.

There is a nice sample project with all the code here:

https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton

It has both text and graphic samples.

Answer (score 0):

It's happened!

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Changes for v7 appcompat library:
        Added SwitchCompat, a backport of the Switch widget that was added in Android 4.0 (API level 14).